# Magento 2 required attribute in custom payment option not working

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, form-validation

I have a custom payment module with select options.

I try to add 'required' to the option but it failed.

I add 'data-mage-init' in  tag and data-validate attribute in  tag.

Should I add anything on js file?

Thanks!

```
<fieldset data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset payment items ' + getCode(), id: 'payment_form_' + getCode()}" data-mage-init='{"validation": []}'>
    <div class="field no-label inst-bank-name required">
        <div class="control">
            <select  name="payment[bankid]"
                     class="select select-bank"
                     data-bind="attr: {id: getCode() + '_bankid', 'data-container': getCode() + '-bankId'},
                                enable: true,
                                options: getBankNames(),
                                optionsValue: 'value',
                                optionsText: 'text',
                                optionsCaption: $t('InstallmentBank'),
                                value: bankId"
                     data-validate="{required:true}">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field no-label inst-bank-period required">
        <div class="control">
            <select name="payment[period]"
                    class="select select-period"
                    data-bind="attr: {id: getCode() + '_period', 'data-container': getCode() + '-period'},
                               enable: true,
                               options: getBankPeriods(),
                               optionsValue: 'value',
                               optionsText: 'text',
                               optionsCaption: $t('InstallmentPeriod'),
                               value: period"
                    data-validate="{required:true}">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I included the following file in my js file.

```
define(
    [
        'underscore',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        '{custom}/js/{custom}/form-builder'
    ],
    function (_, $, Component, url, customerData, errorProcessor, fullScreenLoader, formBuilder) {
        'use strict';
....
```

Comment: which issue you are facing?

Comment: nothing happened after I add required. I still can send the form without option selected.